# Type signature types for lists, etc

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

How would you define the following type signatures in plain english:

```
Ord a => ...

Eq a => ...

Num a => ...
```

Could you describe the meaning of these and let me know what the differences are (in terms of how I would explain it to someone else)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are all examples of "class constraints": they constrain what types can be used in place of the type variable which follows them (`a` in this case), requiring that it belong to a particular [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). `Ord`, `Eq` and `Num` are examples of type classes.

- `Ord a => ...` means `a` is a type which has a natural notion of order associated with it. For example, integers can be naturally arranged from smaller to larger. In mathematical terms, there exists a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on `a`. An obvious example a function which requires this constraint is `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`; read this signature as saying that `sort` only works on lists of things which can be put in order relative to one another.
- `Eq a => ...` means `a` is a type whose members can be compared to each other for some notion of equality. In mathematical terms, there exists an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on `a`. Note that this is a superclass of `Ord`, meaning anything that has a notion of ordering must also have a notion of equivalence. An example of a function which requires this constraint is `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` (which determines if a list contains a given element); read this signature as saying that `elem` only works on lists of things which can be compared to one another for equality. If you think about how you would write `elem` yourself, that should make sense.
- `Num a => ...` means `a` is a numeric type, meaning it supports some basic arithmetical operations: `+`, `*`, `-`, `abs`. I believe this is roughly similar to the mathematical notion of a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29). Basically all the types you think of as "number types" belong to this class: `Int`, `Double`, etc. You would see the `Num a =>` constraint in front of a signature if the function was written to work generically with any kind of number. For example, `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`, which sums all the elements of a list of numbers, can work equally well on `[Int]`, `[Double]`, `[Rational]`, etc... all it has to do is add up its contents, no matter what kind of numbers they are. But numbers they must be!

Basically, these type classes/constraints are an approach to "principled overloading" of functions. We can use `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` on various types, but *not just any types*. Some things, for example functions, don't make sense to compare for equality (perhaps because equality isn't decidable for that type), and it *never* makes sense to compare two things of *different* types for equality (contrast this with Java, where you can compare any two objects of possibly different types for equality).

For further (very accessible) reading on type classes and constraints, I highly recommend [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).

Comment: I think people often expect `(==)` to be a congruence relation rather than an equivalence relation.  Of course, Haskell doesn't force you to make it either.